# Taylor expansion of $\mathbf{u}$ along solutions of $\mathbf{u}' = \mathbf{f}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

Let $\mathbf{u}\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and suppose $\mathbf{u}$ satisfies $\mathbf{u}' = \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u}, t)$.

To first order, Euler's method says
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{u}(t+h) = \mathbf{u}(t) + h \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u}, t) + \mathcal{O}(h^2)
\end{align*}
and to second order
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{u}(t+h) = \mathbf{u}(t) + h \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{u}, t) + \frac{h^2}{2} \left[\nabla_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{f}\cdot \mathbf{f} + \frac{\partial \mathbf{f}}{\partial t}  \right]
\end{align*}
However, I have not been able to derive the Taylor expansion to arbitrary order, and even the notation seems to be ambiguous and problematic.

What is the formula for the Taylor expansion of $\mathbf{u}$ to arbitrary order when $\mathbf{u}' = \mathbf{f}$?

Comment: See Butcher trees and associated constants, as explained for instance in https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/RK-methods.pdf, starting at slide 23

Comment: @LutzL: Very helpful. But it looks like he's only considering the autonomous case?

Comment: You can always rewrite an ODE system as autonomous by adding time as a state component with derivative constant $1$.